# Mobile app redirection not working as expected

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

How can be dectected if mobile app redirection is failing? Instead of setTimeOut I need something else, so it can be redirected to play market only in case if I don't have app installed.

```
window.location.href = APP_LINK;

setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.href = PLAY_MARKET_LINK;
}, 5000);
```